# How do I add real folders to my Netbeans C project?

Tags: c, netbeans, ide, directory

How do I add real folders to my C project in Netbeans. I know I can make 'logical' directories but I'd like to also have my files sorted in directories while browsing trough the filesystem.

Adding a folder using "New->Folder" creates a folder in the filesystem, but all files located in it are displayed as if they were in the root inside Netbeans. The folder is not displayed at all.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your folder must  contain a Makefile